# One box - one pair -2 different things to create 4 length

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve exercise that has to do with Combinations and Permutations.I think it is Permutation because if it was Combination we care about the order.
I have stacked in an exercise and I would like to give me your help.

How many with length 4 can I create from  a box ( the box has 24 balls)  with 1 pair at least that has successively white balls or successively black balls. The white balls are 7 the black balls are 17.

What I did is
to take `P(n,r)=n!/(n−r)!`

so for Pwhite(7,2).
I did this, because I take 7 black ball and I want 2 pair so I have the result

```
Pwhite(7,2)=7!(7-2)!= 42
```

Now the black Pblack(17,2)
`P(17,1)=17!/(17−2)!`
I have the result **272**

I want to do 4 length of 2white and 2black(as I understand - maybe I am wrong).

Comment: What was the original question ?

Comment: How many with length 4 can I create from a box ( the box has 24 balls) with 1 pair at least that has successively white balls or successively  black balls. The white balls are 7 the black balls are 17.

Comment: Sorry Maikl. I still don't get it. There is a box with $7$ white balls & $17$ black balls ... & this is the point where I get lost.

Comment: no the box has 24 balls. 7 of those 24 balls are white and 17 out of 24 are blacks.

Comment: I think you're asking how many sequences of $4$ balls can you draw (without replacement) from a box with $7$ white balls and $17$ black balls such that the sequence has at least one pair of same-colored balls adjacent to each other.  Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertShore exactly as you wrote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, the question is how many sequences of $4$ balls can you draw (without replacement) from a box with $7$ white balls and $17$ black balls such that the sequence has at least one pair of same-colored balls adjacent to each other.

As is often the case for such problems, it's easier to subtract the "bad" combinations from all combinations, thereby yielding the number of good combinations.

Since order counts (otherwise it's meaningless to take about balls being adjacent to each other), there are $\frac{24!}{20!}$ possible sequences, ignoring the restriction.  The only "bad" sequences contain exactly $2$ white balls and $2$ black balls in the order WBWB or BWBW.

There are $17 \cdot 16$ ways to choose the two black balls in order and $7 \cdot 6$ ways to choose the two white balls in order.  For each of these choices, there are $2$ bad combinations.  Therefore, the total number of bad combinations is $2 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$.  Subtract that number from $\frac{24!}{20!}$ and what remains is the number of combinations satisfying our conditions.

Comment: What if we have  instead of White ball we had group1 (white,green,red,blue,orange,black,grey) and instead of black ball we had other 17 different colours,lets call it group2? how could I calculate it this?I have seen and similar exercise like this that's why I am asking and you have to do the same thing to fit-together the group1 with group2

Comment: It's very difficult to answer your question because I don't understand your proposed alternative question.  At any event, this is probably best asked as a separate question rather than as a comment to this question.  Please try to clearly express your new question when you write it, and don't forget to tell us what you've tried.  By the way, if you find an answer useful, an upvote as well as an acceptance is appreciated.